# Updating a value in a function through another function or from outside of the first function?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have written a very simple code to have a scatter plot. I wondered to know how I can replace the figure by introducing a new `y-axis` through a `second function`, and updating the figure. in this example, I can plot based on the values for `x, y1`. I want to know if I got new values such as `y2` through another function, how to update the figure?

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = Tk()

def plot():
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    y1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1]
    plt.scatter(x, y1)

    plt.title('Test')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')

    plt.show()

def update():
    y2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

my_button1 = Button(root, text="plot", command=plot)
my_button1.pack()

my_button2 = Button(root, text="update", command=update)
my_button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you could use a global variable.

Comment: @Barmar I dont want to pass the variable over the first function.  I look for a way to update the variable from the outside the first function.

Comment: you can't access local variables from outside the function.

Comment: @Barmer I have seen we can use config() to change the values inside a widget. Isn't there a way to do that for variables?

Comment: No, it's not possible to do that for variables. The widget is in a class, it provides methods to change the values of attributes. You could write a class for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a global `y` list. The `plot()` function reads that global variable and the `update()` function updates that global variable (and then calls `plot()` after clearing the figure with `plt.clf()`) :

```py
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = Tk()

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1]

def plot():
    # if you want it to be reversible, add :
    # global y
    # y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1]
    # plt.clf()

    plt.scatter(x, y)

    plt.title('Test')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')

    plt.show()

def update():
    global y
    y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    plt.clf()
    plot()

my_button1 = Button(root, text="plot", command=plot)
my_button1.pack()

my_button2 = Button(root, text="update", command=update)
my_button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed it works for this example. however, I still have a problem with my case. I think I need another post to be more precise with my case.

Answer (score 2):

Make the Y values a global variable. You can also make `x` automatically adapt to the length of this, instead of hard-coding 9 elements.

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = Tk()

y_values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1]

def plot():
    x = list(range(1, len(y_values)+1))
    plt.scatter(x, y_values)

    plt.title('Test')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')

    plt.show()

def update():
    global y_values
    y_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

my_button1 = Button(root, text="plot", command=plot)
my_button1.pack()

my_button2 = Button(root, text="update", command=update)
my_button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Barmer, Thanks for your reply. this code doesn't update the figure

Comment: You may need to reset the figure or delete the old one and create a new one. I don't know matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the data into parameters, you can invoke the function twice, which will plot the new graph after the first window is dismissed:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1]

def plot(x, y):
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    plt.title('Nuage de points avec Matplotlib')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.savefig('ScatterPlot_01.png')
    plt.show()

plot(x, y)

y2 = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
plot(x, y2)
```

If you want to have a different title or save to a different `.png`, you can further add parameters to `plot()`:

```
title = 'Nuage de points avec Matplotlib part2'
filename = 'ScatterPlot_02.png'

def plot(x, y, title, filename):
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.savefig(filename )
    plt.show()

plot(x, y2, title, filename)
```